# Kernel API to know up address of interface

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, kernel

Is there any kernel side/space API to know the ip address of an interface , given it's name?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `rtnetlink` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/rtnetlink))

> Rtnetlink allows the kernel's routing tables to be read and altered.
> It is used within the kernel to communicate between various
> subsystems, though this usage is not documented here, and for
> communication with user-space programs. Network routes, IP addresses,
> link parameters, neighbor setups, queueing disciplines, traffic
> classes and packet classifiers may all be controlled through
> NETLINK_ROUTE sockets.

According to `strace`, tt's the api `ip addr show dev XXX` uses:

```
strace ip addr sh dev lo 2>&1 | grep sendmsg

sendmsg(4, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=48, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST, seq=1596838225, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=0, ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, [{{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 9}, {{nla_len=7, nla_type=IFLA_IFNAME}, "lo"}]}, iov_len=48}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 48
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=40, type=RTM_GETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST, seq=1596838225, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=if_nametoindex("lo"), ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0}, {{nla_len=8, nla_type=IFLA_EXT_MASK}, 9}}, iov_len=40}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 40
```

However, it looks like a non-trivial api so if you don't need it often, it might be easier to just run `ip addr sh dev XXX` and parse the response.

Edit:

Looks like it's also possible using `netdevice` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/netdevice)), specifically, the `SIOCGIFADDR` ioctl:

> SIOCGIFADDR, SIOCSIFADDR
> Get or set the address of the device using ifr_addr. Setting the interface address is a privileged operation. For compatibility, only
> AF_INET addresses are accepted or returned.

There's example code [here](https://www.binarytides.com/c-program-to-get-ip-address-from-interface-name-on-linux/)